# Extension of intersection of ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let $f:A \rightarrow B$ be a ring homomorphism and $\mathfrak{a}_1,\mathfrak{a_2}$ be ideals of $A$. Let $\mathfrak{a}^e$ denote the extension of an ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ of $A$ in $B$. An exercise shows that
$$(\mathfrak{a}_1 \cap \mathfrak{a}_2)^e \subseteq \mathfrak{a}_1^e \cap \mathfrak{a}_2^e.$$

It seems that $(\mathfrak{a}_1 \cap \mathfrak{a}_2)^e =\mathfrak{a}_1^e \cap \mathfrak{a}_2^e$ is wrong in general, but I can not find a counter-example.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint.** Try a ring extension which is not flat (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1110376/flatness-and-intersection-of-ideals) why), e.g. $K[X^2,X^3]\subset K[X]$. (I leave you the pleasure to choose the right ideals.)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a general method for producing counter-examples in algebra that often works.

Let us try to find a universal counter-example to your statement where the ideals $\frak a_1$ and $\frak a_2$ are principal. The universal ring having $2$ principal ideals is the ring
$$
A=\mathbf Z[x,y]
$$
with the principal ideals ${\frak a}_1=(x)$ and ${\frak a}_2=(y)$. Since $A$ is a UFD, one has ${\frak a}_1\cap{\frak a}_2=(xy)$.
One wants to construct a morphism of rings $f\colon A\rightarrow B$ such that $(xy)^e\subsetneq (x)^e\cap(y)^e$ in $B$. This strict inclusion means that there is a multiple of $x$ in $B$ which is also a multiple of $y$ in $B$, but which is not a multiple of $xy$ in $B$.

Let $B$ be the ring one obtains from $A$ by adjoining an element $z$ such that the multipe $zx$ is equal to the multiple $zy$. More precisely, let
$$
B=\mathbf Z[x,y,z]/(zx-zy).
$$
Let $f\colon A\rightarrow B$ be the natural morphism. Everything has been devised such that
$$
zx=zy\in(x)^e\cap(y)^e.
$$

Let us prove that $zx\not\in (xy)^e$. This can be done in several ways. Here is one. It suffices to show that $zx$ is nonzero in the quotient ring
$$
C=B/(xy)=\mathbf Z[x,y,z]/(zx-zy,xy).
$$
We can even take a smaller quotient and show that $zx$ is nonzero there:
$$
D=C/(x-y)=\mathbf Z[x,y,z]/(x-y,xy)=\mathbf Z[x,z]/(x^2)=(\mathbf Z[x]/(x^2))[z]
$$
The image of $zx$ in $D$ is obviously nonzero. It follows that $zx\not\in (xy)^e$.

Comment: 1. I don't understand very well what you mean by "a universal counter-example". 2. Maybe we don't need a third variable, and factorize by $x^3-y^2$, let's say, in which case we get $\mathbb Z[X^2,X^3]$ which looks very familiar to me.

Comment: A last remark: if $R$ is an integral domain, and $I\subset R$ an ideal, then $R/I$ is $R$-flat iff $I=0$. This shows that your construction is part of the "non-flat" setting.

Comment: @user26857: 1. Universal means that for every example of a morphism $f'\colon A'\rightarrow B'$ and ideals ${\frak a}_1'$ and ${\frak a}_2'$ of $A'$ such that $({\frak a}_1'\cap{\frak a}_2')^e\subsetneq ({\frak a}_1')^e\cap({\frak a}_2')^e$, there is are morphisms $g\colon A\rightarrow A'$ and $h\colon B\rightarrow B'$ such that $h\circ f=f'\circ g$, and $h(zx)\in ({\frak a}_1')^e\cap({\frak a}_2')^e$, but $h(zx)\not\in({\frak a}_1'\cap{\frak a}_2')^e$.

Comment: @user26857: 2. The question is not wether we need a third variable or not, the question is about a counter-example. If one knows that counter-examples have something to do with nonflatness, then, of course, one can look for examples as you gave in your answer. What I wanted to contribute is a general method of attacking such problems. That's all.

Comment: @user26857: 1. Another way to explain what universality means here is the following. If the proof I gave would not have worked, i.e., if I would have found that $zx$ did belong to $(xy)^e$, then that would have proved that the extension of the intersection of two principal ideals is always equal to the intersection of the extensions, for all morphisms of rings!

Comment: Ok. Now let me add an alternative proof for $zx\not\in (xy)^e$: note that $x$ is not a zerodivisor in $B$ since it is coprime with $z(x-y)$, so $zx\in xyB\implies z\in yB\implies z\in(y,zx-zy)=(y,zx)$, a contradiction.